# Cordova Push Notification plugin, AWS SNS notifications works in-app; how do I create a native Android notification?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using the PushNotification plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and am correctly receiving messages sent from AWS SNS.  When I "Publish To A Topic" the message "just testing", I get the following from the plugin on-registration callback:  `{"additionalData":{"default":"just testing","collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","foreground":true}}`  While not what I was expecting according to the PushNotification docs, I can still use it.

To get that to show up as an Android OS-level notification (the ones that show up on the lock screen), do I need another plugin (eg: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) or am I simply missing something?

Comment: Did you manage to fix that? Can you also post the code necessary to have AWS SNS Working with Cordova?

Comment: No, didn't get it working.  I ditched the project a few days later.  Sorry.

Comment: i discover how to do it, check my answer.